# Getting to a list of lists in Groovy

Tags: groovy

I have an Object `MyObject` which has a List of `ThatObjects` where each `ThatObject` is a list of  `ThoseObjects`.

```
MyObject {
    List<ThatObject> thatObjects;
}

ThatObject {
    List<ThoseObject> thoseObjects
}
```

If I have a handle to MyObject, is it possible to get a handle to all thoseObjects in one list joined to together?  Without have to iterate and make the joined list myself?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given:

```
class MyObject {
    List thatObjects
}

class ThatObject {
    List thoseObjects
}
```

We can make a test object of:

```
def o = new MyObject( thatObjects:[ new ThatObject( thoseObjects:[ 1, 2 ] ),
                                    new ThatObject( thoseObjects:[ 3, 4 ] ) ] )
```

Then a simple walk through the properties gives us:

```
assert o.thatObjects.thoseObjects == [ [1, 2], [3, 4] ]
```

And call `flatten` to get a single list:

```
assert o.thatObjects.thoseObjects.flatten() == [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ]
```

Or, you could use `collectMany`

```
assert o.thatObjects.collectMany { it.thoseObjects } == [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ]
```